# React rendering before state set after two axios api get requests

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-effect, use-state

I am trying to make two calls via axios, wait for those responses, set the corresponding variables using useState, set isLoading to false, and then render my React app. I cannot get `fleets` to be loaded before the app tries to render. The app tries to render while `fleets` is still null resulting in `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null`. What is the best approach to fix this? Why is my chain of `.then`'s not working?

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {

  const DEFAULT_FLEET = "My Fleet"
  const [selectedFleet, setSelectedFleet] = useState(DEFAULT_FLEET);
  const [contracts, setContracts] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [fleets, setFleets] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    Promise.all([
      axios.get('/fleets'),
      axios.get('/contracts?fleet_name=' + selectedFleet)
    ])
    .then(([fleetsResponse, contractsReponse]) => {
      setFleets(fleetsResponse.data);
      setContracts(contractsReponse.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      setError(error.message)
    })
    .then(console.log(fleets))
    .then(setIsLoading(false))
    
  }, [])

  if (error) {
    return (<>Error: { error }</>)
  } else if (isLoading) {
    return (<div>Is Loading...</div>)
  } else {

    const fleetOptions = fleets.map((fleet) => {
      <option value={fleet.name}> {fleet.name} </option>
    });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select>
        {fleetOptions}
        </select>
      <div>{ contracts }</div>
    </div>
  );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, the argument to `then` should be a function that will be called when the promise fulfill. In your code, `setIsLoading(false)` is executed when the promises are still fetching. Try changing:

```
-    .then(setIsLoading(false))
+    .then(() => setIsLoading(false))
```